# How can I make a program that count features' attributes in qgis?

Tags: python, qgis

I made the program that count features.
Code is Below is the following.

```
from osgeo import ogr
import os
path = 'C:/~'
datasource = driver.open(tree,0)
layer = datasource.Getlayer()
featureCount = layer.GetFeatureCount()
print("path = ", featureCount)
```

How can I add the code for counting each attributes?
I need help, not doctor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on what you mean by count the attributes. But once you have a layer it is [easy to iterate through the features and access the attributes of each feature](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html#accessing-attributes):

```
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
     print(feature['name'])
     print(feature[0])
```

You can also query the layer for details of the attributes that each feature will have:

```
for field in layer.fields():
    print(field.name(), field.typeName())
```

Comment: If there is the layer called sector, in that layer has alpha, bravo, charlie attributes
and I want to count each attributes
If you want to need more explanation I'll edit the question

Comment: what sort of attributes are they? numbers, strings? do you want to count types or sum the values? All of these are possible - I've shown you how to access the attributes what you do with them is really up to you

Comment: there are 12 layers and each layers' attribute are strings or numbers

Comment: And I want to count sum of the value.
For example, the layer called tree in the table the number of features are 1000, and attributes are maple, bamboo, pine and I want to count each of attributes
maple = N
bamboo = N
pine = N

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using The ExecuteSQL method of ogr.DataSource to obtain the information you need.  A SQL Statement of

SELECT Count(*) as count, species
FROM tree
GROUP By species

Would give you counts of each species of tree in the tree layer.  Even if the the Driver doesn't support SQL you can use the SQLite Dialect.

Here is the link to the Documentation.
https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.ogr.html#osgeo.ogr.DataSource